# How to activate progress bar on scroll using waypoints?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-waypoints, onscroll

I want to activate my progress bar on scroll and use `waypoints.js` for that. However it's not working and the progress bar is either 'filled' before I scroll over or ([like in my current code](https://jsfiddle.net/codingcodingcoding/x1wnqsqn/7/)) remains 'empty' on scroll as well as on page load.

html:

```
<div id="progress-bar-start" class="center-block progress-wrapper">
    <h4>UI/UX Design:</h4>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="max-width: 60%">
            <span class="title">60%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#skills {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  .skills-title::first-letter {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: pink;
  }
  .progress-wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    .progress-bar {
      background-color: pink;
      width: 0;
      animation: progress 1.5s ease-in-out forwards;
      .title {
        opacity: 0;
        animation: show 0.35s forwards ease-in-out 0.5s;
      }
    }
    .progress {
      height: 40px;
    }
  }
  @keyframes show {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

js:

```
$('#skills').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === 'down') {
        $('.progress-bar').addClass("show");
    } else {
        $('.progress-bar').removeClass("show");
    }
}, {
    offset: '50%'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things to note here.

- First, let's start with Waypoint's `offset` option: By default a waypoint triggers when the top of the element hits the top of the window. The `offset` specifies the triggering distance between these top positions.
  In your example it is important to note, that the `#skills` section sticks to the top of the window, which means that with an `offset >= 0` it triggers immediately at pageload, and only once (with 'down' direction).
- Second, in order to show the progress bar progressing, you have to set the `width` of the bar, as opposed to the visibility/display. Also, setting the width should be done via the `width` instead of the `max-width` attribute, as that is needed to run the css animation.

So, the solution is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress">
    <!-- CHANGE style="max-width: 60%" TO data-score="60%" -->
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" data-score="60%"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#skills').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === 'down') {
        $('.progress-bar').width(function(){
            // this here refers to individual .progress-bar items
            return $(this).data('score');
        });
    } else {
        $('.progress-bar').width(0);
    }
}, { offset: '10%' });
```

**SCSS**

```
#skills {
  margin-top: 100px;
  /* …the rest is the same… */
}
```

Working example available on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dferenc/w9h042t2/) as well.

**UPDATE** (answer for a comment):
In case you would like the animation to happen every time the user scrolls down, but do not show the decreasing animation of the progress bar in the meantime you can alter the code as follows:

```
$('#skills').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === 'down') {
        $('.progress-bar').width(function(){
            // this here refers to individual .progress-bar items
            return $(this).data('score');
        });
    }
}, { offset: '10%' });

$('#skills').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === 'up') {
        $('.progress-bar').width(0);
    }
}, { offset: '100vh' });
```

The code above still runs the decrease animation, but when not running in an iframe (like in Fiddle) that wont be visible as it got triggered when the `#skills` is out of the viewport. (In this case you might make use the visibility classes too.) 
In order to better showcase the functionality, I have also set `margin-top: 100vh;` on `#skills` in this [Fiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/dferenc/w9h042t2/3/).

Comment: Thank you so much, it works great. Could you tell me, how I can make it that on up scroll the bars stay 'filled' and the animation only happens on down scroll -instead of returning back to 0 on up scroll?

Comment: Happy to help. If you want the bars to stay on, than you just have to delete the else statement in the javascript.

Comment: I tried to do that at first, but then whats happening is that the bars also wont 'reload' on scroll down. So the are being triggered only once and I wanted them to be triggered always on scroll down and stay on scroll up. I was also trying to change the offset so they will still be triggered every time (on scroll down and up) but its not visible anymore on scroll up but that doesnt really work..

Comment: @javascript2016 Updated the answer to account for this question as well.